# Docker Windows Vs VM Ubuntu Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am fairly new and want to learn Docker and Containers, specifically web app architecture. My question is what path should I go to, if I just install Docker Desktop on Windows or just install a VM and run an ubuntu then the docker?
Thanks...

Comment: The Linux version has a lot more stability than Docker Desktop.

Comment: You should opt for docker-desktop first because it has docker-compose installed and networking done by windows's hyper-v .I recommend docker-desktop with wsl2 enabled . Good luck